# JAVA - `.properties` files - how to handle in angular 5

Tags: javascript, java, angular, angular5

I require to load some datas from `.properties` files from server. how to load and read that kind of files in angular 5.0?

here is my try :

```
async resolve(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot){

        const response = await this.getCountryName(); 
        let countryPath  = this.countryDetails.countryShortName.toLowerCase() + '_' + this.countryDetails.countryShortName;
        let $dataUrl = `/assets/data/${countryPath}/${countryPath}.json`;
        let $propUrl = `/assets/data/resource.properties`;

        let $dataData = this.http.get($dataUrl);
        let $propData = this.http.get($propUrl);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            forkJoin([$dataData,$propData])
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log( 'both', data[0], data[1] );
                resolve(data);
            });
        })

    }
```

But getting an error as :

`Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/assets/data/resource.properties`

what is the correct way to handle? and how to read and added to template file?

Any one help me?

Comment: The url seems to hit your angular application only and not the server.

Comment: at present I am trying to read the `.properties` file from my local system. will replace with server\